# How to Implement Scheduled Task in Spring Web Service?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, timertask

I am developing Java REST Web Service using Spring and Hibernate. I need to implement a feature to schedule a future task. For example, When User Sign Up in my application I have to credit him 100 virtual credits to his account for first six months. Like this there is some more similar features.

I am thinking like `TimerTask` can be used for this feature. The problem is If I create `Timer` for each users who sign up, I can't able to stop `Timer` of specific user if he goes inactive and it seems like dumping Thread in memory. If 1000 users sign up there will be 1000 `TimerTask` Threads.

How to implement this kind of feature using Spring or Java? I should have the full control over the Thread, I can able to stop thread If I want.

Comment: and you are sure your program is running this long without a need to restart or a failure forcing restart? I think you rather need a solution to store this data somewhere and regularly checking the timed conditions

Comment: Yes. I am using Tomcat Server. It will crash sometime and go down, then I need to restart server to get it back.

Comment: see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Single thread to perform a task with @scheduled annotation and minimal XML configuration, I'll leave the link for your  [reference](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks).

you're just required to create a method in your service and place @Scheduled annotation like

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression(){
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
}
```

Comment: Yes by using this I can schedule a Job. But how can I stop the Job. If I scheduled Job to execute for each 10 mins and for some reasons I want to stop this execution, How can I do that?

Comment: Don't try to stop the job! Instead have a Boolean check inside scheduled task! And you can change the Boolean variable to stop and start the service... Kindly upvote and accept my answer if it works!

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to do. Because actually `TimerTask` is running and it will run forever.